# Too many redirects, trying to add 301 redirects from http to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to convert my Wordpress site to HTTPS. I've mostly completed this now, but I would like to add 301 redirects to https. Every time I add the additional redirect code to my htaccess, my site falls over with 'too many redirects'.

This is my existing htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm trying to merge the following redirects with the above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ukuleleclub.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ukuleleclub.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ukuleleclub.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Can anyone help me achieve that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule redirects **www.yourSite.com** to **www.yourSite.com** and it causes the Redirect loop. You need to check the %{HTTPS} variable to redirect non-https to https :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```